# Prevent FieldDoesNotExist in Django app on production server during migration

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I run migration on server in this way:

1. Upload models.py file to server with some new field `sfield` im model `Mobject`
2. Perform makemigration command in manage.py
3. perform migrate command in manage.py
   But there are some requests between end of first step and end of third step which are failed with `django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: Mobject has no field named 'sfield'` (Which is obvious, becouse django ORM can't fetch this field from DB but field already in Class, so django will try to do it)

Is it possible to make all 3 steps "Atomic"? Or globaly ignore this exceptions, becouse for now I don't need `sfield`, I only want perform migration without Exceptions. Or may be I can temporarely mark new field in some way to prevent django fetching it from DB, but it must be visible for makemigrations/migrate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you do `select * from yourtable` then django tries to fetch all fields defined in the model.

you can use [only()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.only) in your orms to select specific fields, so that no exception will be raised while migrating new fields that are not used in orm yet

btw, you should create migration files locally, test the new field on your local machine and then commit the migration files to server. In server while deploying, you then need only `migrate` right after deployment, which makes the time shorter where exceptions can happen.

from the django docs:

> The reason that there are separate commands to make and apply
>   migrations is because you’ll commit migrations to your version control
>   system and ship them with your app; they not only make your
>   development easier, they’re also useable by other developers and in
>   production.

Comment: Thank, Yes, I agree - local develoment server is correct approach for creating migrations, but as you mentioned it will not solve problem, it will  reduce server migration steps to 2: `Upload` and `migrate` but still some request may be failed. Only is interesting thing, thanks to your unswer I also found `defer`, I will try it also.